# Google Advanced Drive API fails on insert of some PDFs but not others

Tags: macos, google-chrome, pdf

function extractTextFromPDF() {

```
// PDF File URL
// You can also pull PDFs from Google Drive

// this Fall2019_LLFullCatalog.pdf will not insert - internal error on insert is all the feedback that gets logged"
// doesn't matter if I retrieve it from the university website or if I first copy it to my google drive and then retrieve it from there
//var url = "https://uwf.edu/media/university-of-west-florida/offices/continuing-ed/leisure-learning/docs/Fall2019_LLFullCatalog.pdf";
//var url = "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive/Fall2019_LLFullCatalog.pdf";

// both of these pdfs will insert just fine. Size is not the issue because this one is much larger than the one I need to insert
var url = "https://eloquentjavascript.net/Eloquent_JavaScript_small.pdf";
//var url = "https://img.labnol.org/files/Most-Useful-Websites.pdf";


var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
var size = blob.getBytes().length;

var resource = {
    title: blob.getName(),
    mimeType: blob.getContentType()
};

// Enable the Advanced Drive API Service
var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {ocr: true, ocrLanguage: "en"});

// Extract Text from PDF file
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
var text = doc.getBody().getText();

return text;
```

}

See comments in code above that describe the problem.

The PDF that I need to insert with OCR is not working - regardless of whether I retrieve it from the original site or retrieve a copy that I put on google drive. However, two other PDF urls will insert just fine and one of them is considerably larger than the one that fails.

What else could be the issue, if not size limitation?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be a bug in the Chrome API.  Not all PDF software is created equal, check if the PDF can be read in Adobe Acrobat as a simple test.